# Tabulator sticky headers without using the height argument

Tags: sticky, tabulator

I want to have sticky headers in Tabulator, and I don't want to use the height variable when creating the table. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:"100px", // Sticky header works
        // height:false,// Use instead of height:"100px", sticky header fails
        // leaving the height argument out, sticky header fails
        columns:[
            {title:"Name", field:"name"},
            {title:"Progress", field:"progress", align:"right", sorter:"number"},
            {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
            {title:"Rating", field:"rating", align:"center"},
            {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", align:"center", sorter:"date"}
        ],
        data: [
            {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1,  dob:"14/04/1984", car:1},
            {id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2,  dob:"14/05/1982", car:true},
            {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:0,  dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
            {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1,  dob:"01/08/1980"},
            {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:16, gender:"female", rating:5,  dob:"31/01/1999"},
            {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:38, gender:"male", rating:4, dob:"12/05/1966", car:1},
            {id:7, name:"Jamie Newhart", progress:23, gender:"male", rating:3, dob:"14/05/1985", car:true}
        ]
});
```

Please see/run this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/middy916/35wa8z2n/17/).

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to version 4.6 and add a max-height of 100% to your table then the table will scroll once it has exceeded the height of the containing element.

The table must have a scrollbar in order for the headers to stay fixed, otherwise it just treats the table as a static element on a page and dosnt overflow

Comment: Thank you for your input. I modified the code to <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-table" id="example-table"/>    and  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", { maxHeight:"100%", But the header is still not sticky (stays at the top as I scroll with the scrollbar). Please see [jsfiddle 4.6.2] (https://jsfiddle.net/middy916/oba9zg17/1/)

Comment: that is because the containing element is allowing it to go bigger than the page. you cannot have it so that the page scrolls and the header remains in the same place. either the table rows exceed the height of the table, then the header will stay or the table is allowed to go to the same height as its rows and the header remains in the same place. those are the two options

Comment: Yes, you exactly right, it works, and my apologies for not paying attention to that detail. Much appreciated sir!

Comment: Great, glad to hear that worked for you! if this helped you, would you mind marking it as the answer so it is easier for others to find. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved via @Oli Folkerd (of course). Using/updating to Tabular 4.6, and setting the maxHeight arguement to 100%. Then the table will scroll with sticky headers within the container element.  Perfect and thank you @Oli Folkerd

See the solution and try it here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmiddy/9d7ofecg/8/)

**HTML**

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-table" id="example-table"/>
```

**CSS**

```css
div.example-table {
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    // height:"100px",  // Sticky header works
    // height:false,        // Use instead of height:"311px", sticky header fails
    // leaving the height argument out, sticky header fails
    maxHeight:"100%", // use this and version 4.6 of Tabulator
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name"},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", align:"right", sorter:"number"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
        {title:"Rating", field:"rating", align:"center"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", align:"center", sorter:"date"}
    ],
    data: [
        {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1, dob:"14/04/1984", car:1},
        {id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2,  dob:"14/05/1982", car:true},
        {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:0,  dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
        {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1,  dob:"01/08/1980"},
        {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:16, gender:"female", rating:5,  dob:"31/01/1999"},
        {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:38, gender:"male", rating:4, dob:"12/05/1966", car:1},
        {id:7, name:"Jamie Newhart", progress:23, gender:"male", rating:3, dob:"14/05/1985", car:true}
    ]
});
```